# Null user input causing UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a python script using psycopg2 to either insert new data or update data in a postgresql database. `hourly_count` is input by a user, and works perfectly when an integer is inserted. It's important that it doesn't input anything if a string is attempted, but I do need it to be able to handle a null input. Right now a null input causes the following UnboundLocalError:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'hourly_count' referenced before assignment
```

If I understand correctly, the int() function in `hourly_count = int(ped[time]) * 6` is what prevents null input.

What do I need to do to allow null inputs without allowing strings?

```
def insert_ped(request_json):

try:
    ped = request_json['counts']['ped']
    for time in ped:
        time = time
        hourly_count = int(ped[time]) * 6

    q = """insert into table (
       time,
       hourly_count
        ) values (
       %s,
       %s
        )"""

    con = make_con()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(q, (
    time,
    hourly_count
    ))
    con.commit()
except Exception, e:
    print e
    yyyy_mm_dd=request_json['counts']['attributes']['date']

    q = """update table set
       time = %s,
       hourly_count = %s"""

    con = make_con()
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute(q, (
    time,
    hourly_count
    ))
    con.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the `hourly_count` before the `try-except`:

```
hourly_count = 0
```

Comment: This solved the UnboundLocalError problem but now gives me `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` which I take to mean I'm still running into the python rules for the int() function.

Comment: Well, you have to check if the dictionary `ped` actually has the `time` item before you use it: `if time in ped: ... int(time[ped]) ...`